# nothing show in designer page After created the html page in .aspx in web form in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, zurb-foundation

i have created the .aspx in webform in visual studio. but after i have created the htmlcoding in source and then i could not see my form filling page in designer view in visual studio?

below i mentioned the html code

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainMaster.master.cs" Inherits="ssweb.Admin.MasterPages.MainMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html >

<html>
<head id="head2" runat="server">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Title" runat="server">
<title>Specialed India</title>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<link href="../../Scripts/css/foundation.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="../../Scripts/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"/>
</head>

<body>

<form >
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<img src="../../Scripts/img/logo.png" />
</div>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

after i analysed well in my code,

then the problem is, if i close the script tag in open tag itself.then  i could not get any thing in designer view
eg:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

if i close the script tag like() below , i can view the changes in designer view.
eg:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```